# Android: Rebind ListView Or RecyclerView Without Refreshing Header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, header

I need to refresh / rebind ListView or RecyclerView contents without refreshing the header item itself.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can not notify part of items in Listview Adapter its a drawback of listView .. And `RecyclerView` does not have a native implementation for headers. First let us know how exactly you are creating headers >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Generally, your header has 0 position in the list, so the header places on the top of your list. So, for your lists, e.g. `RecyclerView` you must initialize the adapter (in case of `RecyclerView` you must create accessor of `RecyclerView.Adapter` class) and this adapter has a lot of methods for updating data in adapter (`notifyDataSetChanged(), notifyItemInserted()` etc.) and you can use one of this methods, depends on your purpose. So, in your case you can use `notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)`.

You can find more information about these methods in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the `header` is at `position 0`:**

**Lets say you want to bind the header once and then stop binding it after refresh:**

**When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to reload, the `onBindViewHolder()` method in the adapter gets called again to refresh the data, keeping that in mind. You can set a boolean so that you bind your header once. So that eventhough the `onBindViewHolder()` is called multiple times the header would bind once.**

```
class Adapter extends ...........{

//use a boolean as a flag
private boolean bindHeader = true;
........
.......
.......

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

..........

if(position == 0 && bindHeader){

//bind the header only for the first time
......
......

//then stop binding after refresh
bindHeader = false;

}else if(position > 0){

//bind the reset of the items here


}


}

..............

..............



}
```